# CMIS to SMB 3 gateway

Tags: cmis, smb

I have a [CMIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) server, and want users to access it as a [SMB 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block#SMB_3.0) server.

```
CMIS server <-----> gateway <-----> SMB 3 clients
```

Is there such a gateway?

Any OS and price is fine *(I would prefer open source and runnable on Linux though)*.

Users should be able to:

- Browse folders of the CMIS server just like if it was a SMB 3 server
- See files
- Download files
- See files' metadata

Bonus for write operations:

- Create files/folders
- Modify files/folders
- Delete files/folders
- Modify metadata

Comment: Have you tried to mount the CMIS and export that mount via regular SAMBA ?

Comment: @Marged: Doing so would lose all of the metadata, I believe. By the way, what product are you thinking of to "mount the CMIS"?

Answer (score 0):

MoSMB, an SMB3 server on linux has the capability to interact with any underlying file/object store. You will need to add a plugin to interact with CMIS APIs.
Currently, MoSMB interacts with any posix filesystem and any S3-compatible object store.
MoSMB can exposes any bucket as an SMB3 share and objects can be browsed as files. It should be easily possible to write a plugin for CMIS server. Checkout the video 'MoSMB 3.0 accessing a  S3 compatible Object Store' at link https://www.mosmb.com/videos/

Comment: Are you affiliated with MoSMB? If yes, please disclose it.

Comment: Yes, I am using it as an smb server

Answer (score -1):

I know 2 servers that can give you what you want.

### Non-open source:

1. Visuality Systems : [NQE](http://visualitynq.com/products/cifs-nqe)(for embedded platform) or [NQS](http://visualitynq.com/products/nq-storage)(for storage platform) depend on your network.

These product are portable to any OS (as much as I know).
The license is commercial(so you have to buy this server) and have very good support.

### Open source

2. [Samba](https://www.samba.org/) server - this should be build-in in your Linux OS.

If you seek for support and porting i suggest the NQS/E, if you just want it to work you can choose the SAMBA server.

Comment: No, these are just SMB servers. They are not gateways from CMIS to SMB.